# How to set WPF Button TextBlock style from another resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm setting in a WPF application the style of a button with this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 -1 1 0"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NotSelectedButton}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ActiveFg}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Selected}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SelectedFg}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NotSelectedButton}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ActiveFg}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NotSelectedButton}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource InactiveFg}" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NotSelected}" />-->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However I want the `TextBlock` in the `ContentPresenter` to use a named `TextBlock` style defined as such:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

To test this style, just a `Button` in a `UserControl` or `Window` suffices: `<Button>`, and the style definitions can go in a resource dictionary (of `UserControl` or `Window`).

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Trivial Solution via Direct Assignment

You can set the style directly by assigning a `TextBlock` as `Content` of each `Button`.

```
<Button>
   <TextBlock Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}"/>
</Button>
```

### Support Text As Content Only

If you are sure that you only put strings as content into your button, you can assign a `ContentTemplate` that contains a `TextBlock` to the `ContentPresenter`. This will not work for other content types in the sense that it would not display them as usual, but just their type name in the `TextBlock`.

```
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 -1 1 0">
   <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}" Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

### Support All Content Types

If you want to support any content type as content of your button, you can define the data template from above in the `ContentPresenter.Resources`. Then, the `ContentPresenter` will only apply it, if the `Content` is a `string`. For all other content types it will work as usual.

```
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 -1 1 0">
   <ContentPresenter.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
         <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}" Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: The last option with ContentPresenter.Resources is perfect.